# Comma-separated column value in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid

I am using `DataGrid` in WPF. I am binding list of `Teacher` class to the `DataGrid`.

```
class Teacher
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Age{get;set;}
   public List<Subject> Subjects {get;set;}
}

class Subject
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Weight {get;set;}
}
```

I have setup the `DataGrid` for columns "Teacher Name", "Age", "Subjects". I wan the third column "Subjects" to have comma-separated list of `Subject` class' `Name` property belonging to `Subjects` property of `Teacher` class.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the class that returns the subject comma seperated using string.Join. Bind the property to the grid.

Check below for using string.Join:

```
List<string> val = new List<string>();
val.Add("A");
val.Add("B");
val.Add("C");

string res = string.Join(", ", from item in val select item);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't we do it without introducing a new property ? Something that provides value for the "Subjects" column at run time ?

Comment: Brij, I have added post to read subjects without property. Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If the Teacher obj is t1.

Try to assign values to grid like:

```
t1.Name
t1.Age
string.Join(", ", from s in t1.Subjects select s.Name)
```

This way no need to add property for subject. Try to do like this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using data binding (ItemsSource property) to bind data to DataGrid, which event of DataGrid to use to assign value to "Subjects" column ?